# Create a status column with results based on another table using a case statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

orders

| order_id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

orders_details

| order_id | sku | ordered | received |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 10 | 10 |
| 1 | xyz | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | abc | 10 | 6 |
| 2 | xyz | 10 | 0 |
| 3 | abc | 10 | 0 |
| 4 | xyz | 10 | 0 |

I would like to add to the orders table a column called status which would have the results 'complete', 'partial' and 'open' based on what has been received in the orders_details table

result I am trying to acheive

| order_id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | complete |
| 2 | partial |
| 3 | open |

The problem is when a different product from the same order_id has a different received result it creates an additional row with the group by.

result I am getting

| order_id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | complete |
| 2 | open |
| 2 | partial |
| 3 | open |

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bFrYguhmcMJ32iFuUcXfDw/3

```
SELECT 
    `orders`.`order_id`,
  (CASE
   WHEN `received` >= `ordered` THEN 'complete'
   WHEN `received` < `ordered` AND `received` != 0 THEN 'partial'
   WHEN `received` = 0 THEN 'open'
   END) AS `status`
 FROM
    `orders`
LEFT JOIN `orders_details` ON `orders_details`.`order_id` = `orders`.`order_id`
GROUP BY 
    `order_id`, `status`
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing something, but I think you just want:

```
SELECT `orders`.`order_id`,
    CASE SUM(received)
        WHEN 0 THEN 'open'
        WHEN SUM(ordered) THEN 'complete'
        ELSE 'partial'
    END AS `status`
FROM `orders`
LEFT JOIN `orders_details`
    ON `orders_details`.`order_id` = `orders`.`order_id`
GROUP BY `order_id`;
```

Here's your [updated DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bFrYguhmcMJ32iFuUcXfDw/5)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hacky, but you can define the order by giving then names of the status an order the should be choosen, and then take the maximum for this order.

```
Zcomplete>partial>open
```

We can  thenremove the additional charatcers

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    `orders`.`order_id`,
  REPLACE (MAX((CASE
   WHEN `received` >= `ordered` THEN 'Zcomplete'
   WHEN `received` < `ordered` AND `received` != 0 THEN 'partial'
   WHEN `received` = 0 THEN 'open'
   END)), 'Z', '') AS `status`
 FROM
    `orders`
LEFT JOIN `orders_details` ON `orders_details`.`order_id` = `orders`.`order_id`
GROUP BY 
    `order_id`
;
```

| order_id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | complete |
| 2 | partial |
| 3 | open |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bFrYguhmcMJ32iFuUcXfDw/1)